# Strip with .exec Regular Expressions Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to strip down a string which is a url.

Example:

```
"http://www.wearepi.com/wp-content/gallery/03-05-2011-asian-escape/img_2377.jpg"
```

I need to strip it down to:

```
"gallery/03-05-2011-asian-escape/img_2377.jpg"
```

i already got something like this:

```
/[^\/]*(?=\.\w+$)/.exec
```

But that just leaves me with:

```
"img_2377"
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What about?

```
var target  = "http://whatever.thing.com/this/that/theother.jfoo";
var matches = /^.*\/(gallery\/.*)$/.exec(target);

console.log( matches[0] );
```

That should have the right capture data in it.

Comment: Thanks! Close! that just adds: gallery/03-05-2011-asian-escape/img_2377.jpg behind the url...

Comment: the problem is. that Url keeps changing depending on the image that has been clicked...

Comment: Does it always have gallery in it?

Comment: Yes it always has gallery in it.

Comment: then what I put will match it, every time.